# Not able to get underline for url and detect space after the url

Tags: ios, swift

I have written this code to detect a url...i.e. if I typed a url into my textview then it should detect that url and show a message. This code is written in textview `shouldChangeTextIn range...`.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if textView == contributeTextView {

      let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
      let matches = detector.matches(in: textView.text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: textView.text.utf16.count))

      for match in matches {
        guard let range = Range(match.range, in: textView.text) else { continue }
         url = textView.text[range]
        print("THIS IS THE URL:-> \(url)")
      }
       return true
    }

    //CODE TO GET URL AS UNDERLINED

      .......

    return true
  }
```

This code is working fine. But if It is a url, then I also want an underline to be shown below that url to indicate it’s a url. For that I have written the below code...

```
  //CODE TO GET URL AS UNDERLINED
   let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
  let range = (textView.text as NSString).range(of: "\(url)")
  attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "\(url)", range: range)

  textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

But it’s not working. What has gone wrong...? 
Also if I write the entire url and press space, where can I know that space has been pressed...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working because the `value` for `addAttribute` is wrong. Here is the correct snippet.

```
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
  let range = (textView.text as NSString).range(of: "\(url)")
  attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: 1, range: range)
  attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: range)
  attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: range)

  textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

[image]

Comment: @asd2 I have updated the answer to show underline also. previously it showed the text as link but not underlined.

Comment: If it works for you, please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: The underline is coming fine @Aks. But there are 2 more concerns...1. The text color of the link should also become blue(tried background & foregroundcolor for attributed string but didn't work). 2.How can I detect if I pressed space after typing the entire url..?

Comment: For text color use the `link` attribute as shown in above example.

Comment: And for other questions, better to create separate question on SO.

Comment: I had mentioned the spacebar issue also with this question only..:)

Comment: In your textview delegate project check for replacementText with space, that's the only way to know if space is entered.